# how to read .avl suffix files into r?

Tags: r

I have downloaded global wetland and lake data from this link:
https://www.worldwildlife.org/pages/global-lakes-and-wetlands-database

I am mainly interested in level 3 however it has files suffixed .avl and .adf, how do I read these into r?

I want them read into a raster format

Comment: There are many posts about loading in `.adf` files into R on SO and elsewhere, like [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132403/how-to-read-adf-files-into-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770554/rasterlayer-in-r). You can't load `.avl` files because it isn't raster data, but a file used by ArcGIS to generate a legend, hence useless in R.

Comment: It's a human readable file format containing serialised data (not unlike json or xml), so you could open it with a text editor and see what it contains. It would be very simple to convert this kind of data to a list in R using `readLines` and some simple text parsing, but it's not clear what you would do with the resulting list. As @caldwellst says, it's useless in R